# DBCC TRACEON (1222) not setting status flag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set deadlock flags in SQL 2008 R2, when I run this command

```
DBCC TRACEON (1222)
```

I get no errors and it says it completed `DBCC TRACEON (1222)` , but when I check the status of the flag its not being set

- `DBCC TRACESTATUS (1222)` .

Is there another way to set this? Why wouldn't this work?

Thanks!

Comment: As you are on 2008 you probably don't need this anyway. You can look in the default system_health extended events session http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thank you  for the link,there was one point which stated like this.."or if the buffer has cycled in the meantime. "..how do we know buffer recycle time,can we log this trace flag output to disk every 20 minutes or so ,so that we are guaranteed to get data even in a busy system irrespective of buffer recycle time

Comment: @TheGameiswar - It uses an in memory ring buffer with max memory of 4MB. Hopefully the buffer isn't cycling and overwriting old events that quickly as it only logs deadlocks, high severity errors or long lock and latch waits so these should all be exceptional. There's nothing stopping people setting up an extended events trace for the deadlock graph and using a persistent target such as a file though.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thank you Martin,i never knew extended events were so helpfull in getting deadlock trace ,i thought of awarding a bounty there  ,but it ended up on the question

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Thanks! That's because at some point you need to select an answer to award it to. But there's a minimum delay before that option becomes available.

Comment: @MartinSmith:Oh,Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
dbcc traceon('someflag')
```

sets trace flag at session level and once session is closed,trace flag will no longer be active

To set traceflags globally use this command..

```
dbcc traceon('someflag',-1)
```

To view those trace flags which are set globally  use this..

```
dbcc tracestatus(-1)
```

Trace Flags will be cleared once the SQLServer is restarted.You need to create them at startup of SQLServer,if you want them to be persisted

[image]

Comment: I did run it with the -1 param as well and it still wasnt set :(

Comment: I am not able to repro this,can you share your sql version